# Gerund supporting or Noun support

Tags: gerunds, uncountable-nouns

I ran into this sentence yesterday and I am wondering whether or not I could change *support* to *supporting*.

> In short, labor's support among the public is heavily concentrated among Democrats.

For me, *support* means encouragement from the public, while *supporting* focuses on the action of supporting, providing help rather than the help that they (the public) give. Therefore, *supporting* is not the right word to use in such a context. What do you think?

Comment: As I know, "supporting" is an adjective, and "support" here is a noun. So you cannot replace a noun with an adjective.

Comment: @Sina **supporting** is also gerund and present participle. The OP asked about the difference between using **gerund** or **noun**. However, you are absolutely right that **supporting** is an adjective and usually used before nouns.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused when it comes to some nouns that have the same form with verbs like _help_, _support_ can both be a **Nour** or a **Verb**. And, because they are verbs, there will be **Gerund**.

Comment: @Cardinal you mean we can use a gerund or adjective after possessive 's', without a noun after it?

Comment: @Ho Quang Trung I think, Languages have a very distinct difference with mathematics- you cannot master them by following generalized rules. Languages are replete with exceptions and collocations and these sorts of things. Personally, I think the only way to become an adapt in Languages is *to try* and *to love* !

Comment: @Sina Although we can use a gerund after a possessive, I was mentioning the OP's intention. I like Sina's **answering** the question !

Comment: How about: Your learning English with me... @Sina

Comment: @ Hồ Quang Trung You used a gurend with a noun. Nothing wrong. I said you cannot use it alone without the presence of a noun like in your question.

Comment: I got it. _Supporting_ shouldn't go alone in this case.

Comment: In the context of this sentence, "support" could also mean approval (for example, in an opinion poll) or a vote for a "pro-labor" candidate in an election.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you can't use *supporting* here, but the main reason is that in English, "<noun>'s supporting" only works when the noun is the *subject* of "support". So, these are all fine:

- the public's support for him
- his support among the public
- the public's supporting him

but this is not:

- *his supporting by the public